# Generate certificate which starts previous day

Tags: linux, openssl, certificate

Trying to generate certificate using command and it is working. is it possible to set the start date as yesterday? Tried multiple options but not working

openssl x509 -req -days 3650 -in /test/Test-1490414390.csr -CA /var/www/html/pos/futurex/GENERIC/Airpay-CA-Devices.cer -CAkey /test/GENERIC/Airpay-CA-Devices-privatekey.pem -CAcreateserial -out /test//Airpay-1490414390.cer

Comment: Why? Are you planning to have some clients connect yesterday to the certificate you are generating today? Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Not programming or development. `openssl x509 -req -CA*` always sets notBefore (start time) to the current time obtained from the OS; on Linux (or Unix) you can change what openssl gets with a syscall wrapper like `faketime`, see e.g. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534466/how-to-correctly-fake-time . If to issue cert(s) you instead set up and use `openssl ca` (which requires a bit of work) that can explicitly specify any `-startdate` and `-enddate` values.

Comment: Found a crossdupe where it's ontopic: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/31607/how-to-set-not-before-value-to-past-when-creating-certificate-request

Comment: @user207421 client system accept certificate generated before 8 hour ,